# .on with toggle jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the function toggle with divs that are dynamically inserted, only instead of running only the specific element, the toggle execute all div content.

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="button-style add-comment"><a href="#">Add Comment</a></p>
    <div class="insert-comment" style="display: none;">
        <textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="insert-comment-text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-comment', function(e){
    $(".insert-comment").toggle(); 
});
```

How do I open just a specific div and not all?

Comment: Specify an `id` to your specific `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you need?

```
$(this).next(".insert-comment").toggle();
```

In fact, if all elements with class `add-comment` are always followed by divs that need toggling, the second selector is just slowing you down:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-comment', function(e){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just change your code relatively, this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-comment', function(e){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Or to be **more specific**, try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-comment', function(e){
    $(this).next(".insert-comment").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to open only the next div. If so, instead of

```
 $(".insert-comment").toggle();
```

use

```
 $(this).next("div.insert-comment").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the link to start "toggling" on the `<a>` tag then use the code below:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".add-comment").onClick(function(){
    $(".insert-comment").toggle();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="button-style"><a href="#" class="add-comment">Add Comment</a></p>
    <div class="insert-comment" style="display: none;">
        <textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="insert-comment-text"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```